# Ruby - Code someone explain the following code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have the following piece of code in [a library](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/_assign_attribute), Could someone explain what does the code ("#{k}=") means in the following piece of code?

```
if respond_to?("#{k}=")
  public_send("#{k}=", v)
else
  raise UnknownAttributeError.new(self, k)
end
```

I understand respond_to is a default function in Ruby but there is no definition/explanation given for this syntax, please help us.

Edited :

I get the exception (`unknown attribute 'token' for PersonalAccessToken. (ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError)`) for the above code

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.7.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.7.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:48:in `_assign_attribute': unknown attribute 'token' for PersonalAccessToken. (ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError)
```

so considering k as 'token', In which scenario will I get the exception (In which scenario It goes to the else state?)

Comment: please add to name of a library, and if you can, add link about that piece of code.

Comment: That's a casual [string literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) with interpolation: if `k` is `"foo"` (or `:foo`), then `"#{k}="` evaluates to `"foo="`.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question, so it should not have Rails tags.

Comment: If `k = "foo"`, the first line would read, "if the default receiver, `self`, responds to the method `'foo='`". `respond_to`'s argument can be a string or a symbol (`:foo=`). See [Object#respond_to?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F).

Comment: @CarySwoveland please check the edited question

Comment: @Stefan please check the edited question

Comment: I don't follow. Did you run that code snippet by itself? If so that will clearly raise exceptions. `respond_to?`'s implicit receiver (`self`) would be `main`, and `k` and `v` would be  undefined. If not (I'd think not), you need to show the class and instance method containing the code snippet.

Comment: No k = token and v = some token value, It is a gitlab code and It thows the exception, so I would like to understand If the k = token why I still get the exception in the else case? What is the condition does it check in the IF block?

Comment: The condition in the `if` clause is the same as `if self.respond_to?("#{k}=")`, but you haven't told us what `self` equals (since `respond_to?` has no explicit receiver `self` is its default receiver). Presumably, `self` is an instance of an unstated class.

Comment: @Harry if `k` is `"token"`, the line becomes `if respond_to?("token=")`. So the `else` branch is executed if the receiver doesn't respond to `token=`. Or slightly simplified: the `UnknownAttributeError` is raised if the (setter) method `token=` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This code `public_send("#{k}=", v)` dynamically calls a setter for what is stored in `k` variable. Consider the following example:

```
class FooBarBaz
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar, :baz

  def set_it what, value
    public_send("#{what}=", value)
  end
end
```

It’s roughly an equivalent to:

```
  def set_it what, value
    case what
    when "foo" then public_send("foo=", value)
    when "bar" then public_send("bar=", value)
    when "baz" then public_send("baz=", value)
    end
  end
```

It’s roughly an equivalent to:

```
  def set_it what, value
    case what
    when "foo" then self.foo=(value)
    ...
    end
  end
```

It’s roughly an equivalent to:

```
  def set_it what, value
    case what
    when "foo" then self.foo = value
    ...
    end
  end
```

---

`respond_to?` is called in advance to check if the setter in indeed defined for this `k` on this instance, to prevent somewhat like:

```
FooBarBaz.new.set_it :inexisting, 42
#⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `inexisting=' for #<FooBarBaz:0x0056247695a538>
```

A modified, correct version of the class in this answer:

```
class FooBarBaz
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar, :baz

  def set_it what, value
    public_send("#{what}=", value) if respond_to?("#{what}=")
  end
end
```

It does not throw an exception.

```
FooBarBaz.new.set_it :inexisting, 42
#⇒ nil
```

Comment: If my param k=token, I am actually getting the exception in else case. In which scenario will I get the exception in the above case?

Comment: When the class does not have a setter for the `token`, e.g. neither `attr_writer :token` nor `attr_accessor :token` not `def token=(value)` is declared. Try to read my answer and **understand** this better.

Answer (score 0):

"#{}" is string interpolation in ruby. so for example:

```
k = 'world'
puts "hello #{k}"
# hello world
```

So in your example it looks like it is creating a string with the value of k and =

e.g.

```
k = 'something'
"#{k}="
# something=
```

If you want to know what k is, you can add `puts k.to_s` in the line above then run the code and check your console.

Better still if you are using something like RubyMine, just use the debugger and stick a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: appreciate for your response But still I didn't understand why the string manipulation comes in IF  check

Comment: This does not answer an original question by any mean. If I could downvote it several times for the absurd advice to use RubyMine, I would do it.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin the question very specifically asks: 'Could someone explain what does the code ("#{k}=") means?'. I have explained what #{} means and given examples. My suggestion to use a debugging tool is for the OP to establish what the variables equate to at run time. I have therefore, contrary to your comment, answered the question that was asked. If you feel you can add more or better answer the question then feel free to contribute. If you feel that the question that was asked was not the right question, or misleadingly phrased then, address the OP. Keep your negativity to yourself

Comment: please calm down,ruby friends. we come to resolve the problem, not fight each other, right?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you saw the `_assign_attribute` method in [this docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/_assign_attribute)

k is the abbreviation meaning of 'key', v is same thing meaning of 'value'

`"#{k}="` is some kind of method name to dynamic method by string literal.

It may be "update" or "create", "split", anything else.

Equal symbol("=") is meaning of they are methods to assign something like this `user.attributes = { :username => 'Phusion', :is_admin => true }`

In the above case, "k" is `.attributes` and "k=" is `attributes=` and "v" is `{ :username => 'Phusion', :is_admin => true }`

And `public_send` is method to send a method in public scope.

As a result `public_send("#{k}=", v)` is meaning of call a method having a name as "k" in public method, and this method will be assigned to "v" as the value.

I hope that this explain help to you.

---

Add some example for comment

k is a input from programmer, therefore it does not match method name in Class or Module.

In Reality, there are common mistake case.

```
class User
  # this attribute can be called from a instance of User
  attr_accessor :name
end

# this causes a error when call assign_attribute
User.new.wrong_name

# this is fine
User.new.name
```

[assignment method reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-attributes-3D)

Comment: why this IF condition is failed is my question "If respond_to?("#{k}=")" ? Why does it goes to else condition?

Comment: I mean, If key k = token, What is wrong in the input, why does it goes to the ELSE condition?

Comment: `Class User` is not a valid ruby syntax. Also, there is no `assign_attribute` in [tag:ruby] and despite the question is tagged with rails, the issue has nothing to do with rails. Downvoted.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thank you for comment about syntax. I'm not sure that he refer about assign_attribute. That's just my guess.